# Angular 5 Stop background scrolling when mat-sidenav-container displayed

Tags: html, css, angular, angular5

I'm creating a new `Angular 5` site that has a `mat-sidenav` but i have an issue with it.

My `mat-sidenav-container` sits under my `position: fixed` main menu which is fine but if the page has a vertical scroll, if the `mat-sidenav` is displayed it too scrolls.

What i'm after is to stop the back content scrolling if the `mat-sidenav` is displayed but i don't know the `CSS` to do this as i have tried all the `position`

**HTML**

```
<mat-toolbar>
    <mat-icon class="subMenuIcon" (click)="sidenav.toggle()" title="Click to open the sub-menu.">reorder</mat-icon>
    <img src="./assets/images/Crest.jpg">LEARNING SITE
    <div class="emptySpace"></div>        
    <mat-icon class="loggedInIcon">person</mat-icon>
    <span style="font-size: 15px">USERNAME</span>
</mat-toolbar>
<mat-sidenav-container>
    <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="over" opened="false">
        <div class="closeButton">
            <mat-icon (click)="sidenav.toggle()" title="Click to close the sub-menu.">clear</mat-icon>
        </div>
        <a (click)="sidenav.toggle()" routerLink="/">
            <mat-icon>person</mat-icon>
            Dashboard
        </a>
        <a (click)="sidenav.toggle()" routerLink="search">
            <mat-icon>search</mat-icon>
            Search
        </a>
    </mat-sidenav>
</mat-sidenav-container>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**CSS**

```
mat-sidenav {
    background-color: gray;
    margin-top: 64px;
    color: #ffffff;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding: 7px;
}

mat-sidenav a {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: block;
}

mat-sidenav a:hover {
    color: #c41230;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.closeButton {
    text-align: right;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.mat-drawer-container {
    position: static;
}

/* Moves the side-nav to below the main menu */
.mat-drawer-backdrop {
    margin-top: 64px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to do it with a bit of `CSS`. not bother that the back content scrolls but now my `side-nav` and backdrop do not move

CSS Used

```
.mat-drawer:not(.mat-drawer-side) {
    position: fixed;
}

.mat-drawer-backdrop {
    position: fixed !important;
}
```

Comment: Did you managed to avoid showing the scrollbar in the main content when the mat-sidenav is displayed?

Answer (score 8):

adding `fixedInViewport="true"` in mat-sidenav may fix the issue, also add `[style.marginTop.px]="56"`

Comment: This helps keep the drawer in place , but the other line messes  up everything.

Comment: There's a `fixedTopGap` attribute you can use instead of manually setting `marginTop` https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/api#MatSidenav

Answer (score 3):

Since `<mat-sidenav #sidenav>` has a template reference variable (#sidenav), `<mat-sidenav-container>` can be fixed (in position) using a conditional style, effectively removing background scrolls when sidnav is opened.

```
<mat-sidenav-container [ngStyle] = "{ 'position' : sidenav.opened ? 'fixed' : 'relative'}">
```

Comment: It does work but with a bug. The page is scroll to the top which is not good.

Answer (score 0):

**METHOD 1**

In your component (where side-nav is located), add a hostListener, where you stop the propagation of your scroll event, then only your sidenav will scroll, not the background.

```
  @HostListener("window:scroll", ["$event"])
  onWindowScroll(event) {
    // prevent the background from scrolling when the dialog is open.
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
```

**METHOD 2**

You can add a scroll listener to your sidenav, and stop the propagation there. add a method in your component, and use it in your html:

in the html, add: 
 `(scroll)="onSideNavScroll($event)"` to your side-nav like this:

```
<mat-sidenav-container (scroll)="onSideNavScroll($event)">
        <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="over" opened="false">
            <div class="closeButton">
                <mat-icon (click)="sidenav.toggle()" title="Click to close the sub-menu.">clear</mat-icon>
            </div>
            <a (click)="sidenav.toggle()" routerLink="/">
                <mat-icon>person</mat-icon>
                Dashboard
            </a>
            <a (click)="sidenav.toggle()" routerLink="search">
                <mat-icon>search</mat-icon>
                Search
            </a>
        </mat-sidenav>
    </mat-sidenav-container>
```

In your component, add this function:

```
onSideNavScroll(event){ event.stopPropagation() }
```

Comment: Note that your variable `event` in `onWindowScroll(event)` is undefined. Apply the following to the first line in method 1: `@HostListener("window:scroll", ["$event"])`. I used this in Angular 6+.

Comment: I tried both options. None of them worked. Do you have any idea how to stop the scrolling on the main content when the sidenav is displayed?

Comment: It is difficult to tell without seeng your code. Maybe you can ask a question, link to this thread, and get some help from there?